# /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: Too many levels of symbolic links

Tags: python, bash, ubuntu-16.04

I updated my ubuntu to 16.04 and tried to use `pip install`.
The following error appeared:

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: /usr/bin/python3.4: bad interpreter: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

How to solve this problem?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you trying to `pip install` globally or in a virtual env?

Comment: I tried both ...

Comment: Have you checked your python and pip path? Try to run `which python` and `which pip` and see what they return.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this command ?

```
python3 -m pip install [your package]
```

I used to have errors like that caused by different versions of python installed